# multisets of cardinality $n$ obtained from $n$ sets.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, permutations, combinations

Assume that the sets $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset A_3 \subset ..... \subset A_n$ have the orders $k_1, k_2, k_3, ... , k_n$ respectively,

then how many multisets $\{a_1, a_2, a_3, ...... , a_n\}$ $($such that $a_1 \in A_1,a_2 \in A_2, ... ,a_n \in A_n)$ can be obtained from the above sets ? is there any simple formula to compute the number of multisets ?

Note that the order in which elements are listed does not matter. Namely, $\{1, 1, 2\}, \{1, 2, 1\} and \{2, 1, 1\}$ denote the same multiset.

EX: if

$A_1=\{1,2\}$,

$A_2=\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$,

$A_3=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$,

then we will have the multisets

$\{1, 1, 1\}, \{1, 1, 2\}, \{1, 1, 3\}, \{1, 1, 4\}, \{1, 1, 5\}$

$\{1, 2, 2\}, \{1, 2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 4\}, \{1, 2, 5\}$

$\{1, 3, 3\}, \{1, 3, 4\}, \{1, 3, 5\}$

$\{1, 4, 4\}, \{1, 4, 5\}$

$\{2, 2, 2\}, \{2, 2, 3\}, \{2, 2, 4\}, \{2, 2, 5\}$

$\{2, 3, 3\}, \{2, 3, 4\}, \{2, 3, 5\}$

$\{2, 4, 4\}, \{2, 4, 5\}$

therefore, we have 23 multisets, which can be easily computed by the formula

$$\sum_{m_1=1}^{2} \sum_{m_2=m_1}^{4} \sum_{m_3=m_2}^{5} 1$$, and this formula can be generalized as follows:

$$(1) \sum_{m_1=1}^{k_1} \sum_{m_2=m_1}^{k_2} ...... \sum_{m_n=m_{n-1}}^{k_n} 1$$

New, let me repeat my question, is there any other formula than formula (1)?

If there is no other formula, is there any way to simplify formula (1)?

If the number of the sets is $n=0$, then we have the question: how many multisets of cardinality $0$ can be obtained from $0$ sets ? I think the answer is $1$ multiset, namely, the empty multiset $\{ \}$, how to obtain that from formula (1) ?